# Solving non square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have a matrix $M$ whose columns are made of basis vectors. I want to know if a vector $v$ is reachable from some linear combination of the columns of $M$, which translates to seeing if the equation $Mx = v$ is solvable. $M$ is rarely square, so I can't just invert to solve.

One thing I want to try involves left-multiplying both sides by $M^T$ then inverting. I would think that $M^TMx=M^Tv$ being solvable means that $Mx = v$ is solvable, but I just want to make sure. Essentially, I don't want any unsolvable configurations of $Mx = v$ becoming solvable in the equivalent configuration of $M^TMx=M^Tv$

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of *rarely square*? Does it have more rows than columns, more columns than rows or just arbitrary

Comment: @jack it can be either over or underconstrained regularly. I have a function to solve for both these cases, but I am just wondering if this transpose-multiplication-inversion will work as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give a *counterexample* which shows that even though $M^T M x = M^Tv$ is solvable the base equation $M x = v$ is not.

Just take
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}\,, \quad
v = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \,.
$$
Obviously $Mx=v$ is not solvable but
$$
M^T M x 
= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} x
= x
\overset{!}{=} M^Tv 
= \begin{bmatrix}1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
is solvable.